# Upload and connect to Access database in EC2 from .NET Web API

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, ms-access, amazon-ec2

Is there a way to have a .NET API upload a Microsoft Access database file to an Ubuntu EC2 instance and then connect to the same database to process data? I have my APIs published as AWS lambdas to AWS in the same account as the EC2 instance.

Right now I do not have any server except the EC2 available for my APIs to use when processing the Access database records.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would be far better to convert the data to some text format, like say csv, maybe even json format.

The problem is to crack open, and read a mdb, or accDB file, you need the microsoft JET data engine, or now the ACE data engine. And they ONLY come in x32 or x64 bit flavors that require the windows OS to work.

And a EC2 instance or service has a GAZILLION different types of options, and thus without know what kind of instance you are paying for, then it such an issue and answewr becomes EVEN MORE beyond the scope of a simple Q&A forum like SO.

I mean, if you need to open a PDF file, then you need some PDF software. If you need to open a Excel file, then you need some kind of Excel library. And lo, and behold, if you need to open and read a mdb or accDB file, then again, you need some library code to read + open that file. You have no more luck attempting to up-load a SQL server mdf file either, unless you have a running instance of sql server on that service.

I doubt VERY much that a general EC2 plan offers the ability to run programs that require 100% windows capability, along with the windows OS - of which a PDF viewer for windows, or in this case a mdb or accDB system that is able to crack open that file, and make sense of that kind of file format.

You would be better as noted to export say to some text type of format before up-loading.

Comment: I think an EC2 instance with Linux on it, which is what was provided to me, is not going to work for reasons you stated above. Without a physical disk or place to put the database file for processing, I am not sure how I would even be able to convert the file to any other format. From what I see, I am getting the file from S3 as a byte[] and there is no way to convert a byte[] to a specific file for processing. Or is there and I am missing something? Unfortunately I have to keep the files stored as MS Access database files.